# How to use Meteor JS to check for and list the names of the folder and files inside one of its folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a "parent" folder containing subfolders.  Within these subfolders I have different files and an image (.png file).

The goal I am trying to achieve is for me to be able to copy and paste this "parent" folder in one of the folders inside the Meteor App and have the Meteor App find this "parent" folder and iterate through the subfolders, retrieving the names of each of the subfolders as well as the name and path of the image (.png file).

For example, the file structure of my app is currently:
./client
./lib
./preston
./private
./public
./server

I'm thinking that maybe the most suitable folder for me to copy and paste the "parent" folder described above is in the private folder.
So after I copy and paste the "parent" folder there...
How do I tell Meteor to look for that folder and check for the details of its contents.
How do I achieve this?
Do I need another package?
Is it possible to use node.js code?
How?
var fs = require('fs'); gives me errors which is a node.js code......

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: dont try to put it inside private folder. because your app restarts every time you change something in that folder. try to save it somewhere outside your app.

Comment: Can you describe a little more what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I have a webpage that I want to display the different images of my inventory.  I however do not want to hard code this one by one.  I'd rather have javascript check the filesystem and get the corresponding name of the item by checking the corresponding folder's name(which is the name of the item).  Then, for the image to be displayed, the javascript code should check the "screenshot.png" file inside that same folder and store the path to it so I may use that path for my html code.  I think node.js code is what I need...I've managed to get node.js to work now: var fs = Npm.require('fs');